# Как заменить одинарные кавычки находящиеся между любыми символами в Sublime Text?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

мне нужно выделить все блоки параметров заключенные в спецеалиные символы <> сами символы используются для разделения блоков. Но когда я пишу это выражение (?<=<<)(.*\n)+(?=>>) выделяеться все блики целиком. Что я делаю не так?

---

**Ожидание:**

---

[image: Ожидание:]

---

**Реальность:**

---

[[image: Реальность][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h89Dv.png)]

Comment: Вы используете жадный квантификатор, попробуйте сделать его более ленивым `(?<=<<)(.*\n)+?(?=>>)` добавив после `+` вопросительный знак. И лучше текст скидывать текстом, что бы была возможность проверить у себя, со скриншотов естественно никто набирать текст не захочет.

Comment: Спасибо все получлось и ваше мнение в будущем учту.

Comment: Почему у Вас такой странный заголовок? В тексте нет одинарных кавычек.